# How to develop and debug .NET Core application running into Docker using JetBrains Rider on Mac

Tags: macos, debugging, docker, .net-core, rider

I have started developing a Web API application using .NET Core 1.1 and JetBrains Rider as IDE.  Lately I have come across the need to run and debug the application hosted in a Docker container, and I wonder if anyone could share the setup on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 7):

In Rider, docker support is provided by the bundled plugin, which is also used in IntelliJ IDEA. Here is a documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html

As for debugging, this is not supported yet, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-742